# command to find the size of a file in unix?

Tags: unix

I have tried 'ls -l', I was thinking the 4th column was the file size but not sure.
Then I tried 'ls -s', but that gave a different result. I also tried 'du' but that only gives size for directory.

Comment: Try to use `du -sh /bin/*` *-represent all the file inside the directory. `ls` will list the directory as `4.0k`, but `du` will list as per the `occupied size`, if `empty` it print `4.0k`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
ls -l /bin/grep
```

Output like

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 175488 July 18  2014 /bin/grep
```

Here 175488 is the size of the file

You may also try with:

```
ls -lh /bin/grep
```

to get a user friendly size

> -h
>
> When used with the -l option, use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte,
>   Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte in order to reduce the
>   number of digits to three or less using base 2 for sizes.

You may also try with:

```
stat -c "+%s"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
 stat filename
```

The second line displays thesize in bytes and in blocs.  For more info:  http://www.manpager.com/linux/man1/stat.1.html

Comment: So in fact you can use `stat -c "+%s"`, as `%s` indicates number of bytes. See `man stat` for more options.

Comment: @user3809938:- ls -s option flag lists file size. Check this:- http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/ls/ls-s.htm

Comment: yes i clicked on the link but for ls -s it gives a value of 4 fro todo.txt and 131 when you use ls -ls. Which one is correct?

Comment: ls -s is the size in blocs

Comment: what does that actually mean?

Comment: bloc size ?  depends on environment variable, either displays in 1K blocs,  or in 512 bytes blocs if environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set (see more here: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this command in your terminal:

```
find [Your Directory] [Your Options] -exec du -h \;
```

`find` has some options like `-type`(for type of file or directory or l for link). or `-iname`(for example -iname "a*" for all files or directories that begin with "a"). or `-size`(for searching with size of files) and etc.

the `-exec` is another option for find-command. that uses for executing a command on files that are found.

so with find-command you can find your files in any directory that you want and then by `-exec` you can execute your command like `du -h` that determines volume of files. just at the end of using `-exec` don't forget that you must use \;